# How do I load first 100 records followed by another 100

Tags: c#, sql

I have 500 record in my database but using sql i can only load 250 records. If I write a query SELECT TOP 500 I get an error - Is there a way i can select top 100 record store 400 somewhere else and when a user clicks next button load another 100 etc...

```
        public List<m> DisplayAll()
    {
       int yr= DateTime.Now.Year; 
        DateTime d= new DateTime(yr, 9, 1);
        DateTime dd= new DateTime(yr+ 1, 9, 1);

        List<m> l = new List<m>();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection...);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select distinct ID, name,sname, etc.. from TableName where Time > @Time And Time < @Time1 ORDER BY ID, name, sname, etc... OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY", conn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", d);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time1 ", dd);
```

I am getting an error "Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'."

Comment: Are you using MS SQL. If yes, then please have a look at the paging options available in MS SQL 2012 with OFFSET FETCH NEXT clause here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx

Comment: in your query--> ORDER WHERE??

Comment: @OLRAC I've corrected that

Comment: @DhruvJoshi i have used something from that documentation but i am getting an error `Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET` i've updated my sql query from my question.

Comment: @user911 I understand that your database is MS SQL server 2012 and not MySQL or a lower version of MS SQL Server

Comment: @DhruvJoshi when click -> help -> about it says SQL Server 2012

Comment: @user911 The version is of the DB and not of the IDE. Try this query select @@Version

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, starting with 2005, you use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and filter by that result, e.g. `BETWEEN 1 AND 100` etc.

Comment: The OFFSET FETCH method suggested by @DhruvJoshi is the better approach if you are on SQL Server 2012.

Comment: i've used this but i am getting 0 record? this is my query `WITH cte AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID,fname, sname) AS ROW,* FROM TableName WHERE Time > @Time and Time <@Time1) SELECT * FROM cte WHERE ROW BETWEEN 1 AND 100`

Comment: Test it without your Time parameters, please, to see if the paging is working at all.

Comment: if i do this: `WITH cte AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID,fname, sname) AS ROW,* FROM TableName WHERE ROW BETWEEN 1 AND 100` i get error saying `Incorrect syntax near '100'.`

Comment: using time it works in database but it does not work in my method - if i place a break point ` command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", d);` i am getting date as mm/dd/yyyy do i have to convert it to yyyy/mm/dd? if yes how do i do it?